# Github api. per_page doesn't work and text is scrambled

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, github

So I'm using Github api to make this profile finder page. But there's a problem. First of all if you observe the "Latest repos" section, try and make a few different searches. It's supposed to only display 3 repositories per search but sometimes it does more than 3 (it repeats some items more than once). Also sometimes the text inside the  (below Latest repos) is scrambled or something like that. It's like it overlaps with other text. Any idea how to fix this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search-user").on("keyup", function(e) {
      let username = e.target.value;

      // make request to github
      $.ajax({
          url: 'https://api.github.com/users/' + username,
          data: {
              client_id: '2b6ea7e23a43591cb35d',
              client_secret: '36c9787ee66083eea83a3c15a53d680d1fe82571'
          }
      }).done(function(user) { // .done is same as success: function(user) {}

          $.ajax({
              url: 'https://api.github.com/users/' + username + '/repos',
              data: {
                  client_id: '2b6ea7e23a43591cb35d',
                  client_secret: '36c9787ee66083eea83a3c15a53d680d1fe82571',
                  sort: 'created: async',
                  per_page: 3
              }
          }).done(function(repos) {
              $.each(repos, function(index, repo) { // VERY IMPORTANT LINE OF CODE
                  $("#repos").append(`
              
                      <div class="well">
                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-7">
                                  ${repo.name}: ${repo.description}
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-3">
                                  <span class="label label-default">Forks: ${repo.forks_count}</span>
                                  <span class="label label-primary">watchers: ${repo.watchers_count}</span>
                                  <span class="label label-success">Stars: ${repo.stargazers_count}</span>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-2">
                                  <a style="line-height: 0; font-size: 12px;"href="${repo.html_url}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default">Go to Repository</a>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>

                  `);
              });
          });

          $("#profile").html(`
          
          <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title">${user.name}</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                          <img style="width: 100%" class="thumbnail avatar" src="${user.avatar_url}">
                          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" target="_blank" href="${user.html_url}">View Profile</a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-9">
                          <span class="label label-default">Repositories: ${user.public_repos}</span>
                          <span class="label label-primary">Public Gists: ${user.public_gists}</span>
                          <span class="label label-success">Followers: ${user.followers}</span>
                          <span class="label label-info">Following: ${user.following}</span>
                          <br>
                          <br>
                          <ul class="list-group">
                              <li class="list-group-item">Company: ${user.company}</li>
                              <li class="list-group-item">Website/blog: ${user.blog}</li>
                              <li class="list-group-item">Location: ${user.location}</li>
                              <li class="list-group-item">Member since: ${user.create_at}</li>
                          </ul>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <h3 class="page-header" style="font-size: 25px">Latest repos</h3>
          <div id="repos" style="line-height: 0"></div>
          `);
      });
  })
});
```

```css
body {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.main {
    font-size: 30px!important;
}

avatar {
    width: 100%
}

h1 {
    font-size: 32px;
}

p {
    font-size: 1.6rem!important;
}

.navbar-brand {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.form-control {
    height: 34px;
    font-size: 1.8125rem;
}

#repos {
    line-height: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://bootswatch.com/4/simplex/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <!-- <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->



    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/simplex/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <title>GitHub Finder</title>
  </head>
  <body>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">GitHub Finder</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        
        <main role="main" class="container">
        
            <div class="searchContainer">
                <h1>Search GitHub Users</h1>
                <p class="lead">Enter a username to fetch a user's profile info and respositories</p>
                <input type="text" id="search-user" class="form-control" placeholder="GitHub Username...">
                <br>
                <div id="profile"></div>
            </div>
        
        </main><!-- /.container -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```